# What is the best Free/Open-Source image conversion library in .NET?

Tags: .net, image-processing, open-source

[System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) has supports for very limited number of image formats

What I am trying to do is, given an image of some format(JPG, TIFF, GIF, or PDF), conver them to other formats.

I am specifically looking for a **free** or an **open-source** versions of library for **.NET**.
Google and Stack Overflow gave me results libraries such as LeadTools (which I abhor and not free) and C/C++ libraries.

---

I did do my research on Stack Overflow but I could not find an answer from following somewhat duplicated questions below.

1. [Most useful free .NET libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries)
2. [What is the most useful .net library you’ve found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233648?sort=votes&page=2#sort-top)
3. [What is the best image manipulation library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library)

Comment: What destination formats do you want? http://imageresizing.net/ supports 6-40 input formats (depending upon which plugins are installed), and supports jpeg, gif, and png output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)?

Comment: I went to check out MagickNet, which is not maintained any more.

Comment: My God! You have a weird sense of "not maintained anymore"! If by that you mean it hasn't been maintained for 5 days then you are correct, but... http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php

Comment: @Vincent: No, by "not maintained", what I meant was for was "MagickNet", which is a .NET interface to ImageMagick. - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#dot-net

Answer (score 2):

PDF isn't exactly an image format.  If you need a free library for handling PDFs specifically you could try http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I was going to use either PDFsharp or iTextSharp for PDF conversion. I guess it'd be better if I remove PDF from the question altogether actually.