# Setting Palette on ASP.net/GDI+ Generated PNG Image

Tags: asp.net, gdi+, png

I just built an application in ASP.net that returns a PNG image.

The resulting image is entirely black on a transparent background. Is there a way to index the image to reduce the file size?

I can not index the new image as it is created because I am using the graphics object which will not allow it.

Thank you very much for the help - I've been searching for ages and i can't seem to figure out how to set this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't do this using straight GDI+ - the built-in PNG encoder is very limited in its support for output color depths... Even if you manage to create an indexed `Bitmap` with a good palette in-memory, you'll still find it written out as a 32bpp PNG. To get the kind of control you need, you'll have to resort to a third-party image library.

#### See:

> - [Convert a 24 bit in memory image to indexed color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727987/convert-a-24-bit-in-memory-image-to-indexed-color)
> - [What is the best Free/Open-Source image conversion library in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719616/what-is-the-best-free-open-source-image-conversion-library-in-net)

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a lot of frustration. Sorry for the slow response.